# PDF given distribution function

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

I am given a distribution $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2(1+|x|)}$$ and I need to find the pdf.
I did the following-

$$f(x)=F'(x)=\frac{2(1+|x|).1 -2.sgn(x).x}{2(1+|x|)^2}=\frac{2+2|x|-2|x|}{2(1+|x|)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you apply the quotient rule on $\frac{u}{v}$, you have identify $v$ to be $2(1+|x|)$ but you did not square the $2$.

Notice that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}\, dx=2.$$

Upon squaring the $2$ as well in the denominator, you should obtain the pdf to be $\frac1{2(1+|x|)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, is that all?

Comment: seems to be so.